# Enumerate Python class properties (not functions)

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties, attributes, enumerate

How do I enumerate functions of a Python class marked with `@property`?

```
class MyClass:
    @property
    def my_property():
        pass
```

Something like this, but there is no lambda filter for `inspect.isproperty`:

```
properties = inspect.getmembers(obj, inspect.isproperty)
```

Apparently, these are known as managed attributes.

Comment: Python 2.x or 3.x? (might not make a difference but good idea to specify)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

`inspect.getmembers(obj.__class__, lambda x: isinstance(x, property))`

Here's how it works exactly (using IPython):

```
In [29]: class Foo(object):
   ....:     @property
   ....:     def foo(self): return 42
   ....:     

In [30]: obj = Foo()

In [31]: inspect.getmembers(obj.__class__, lambda prop: isinstance(prop, property))
Out[31]: [('foo', <property at 0x106aec6d8>)]
```

This works because `property` is a normal (new-style) class really; by marking something with `@property`, you're just making an instance of `property`. This also means that instances of properties (on a class) can be type-compared against `property` using `isinstance`.

Comment: you can use dir too, then you won't need to import inspect `[isinstance(getattr(obj.__class__,prop),property) for prop in dir(obj.__class__)]` **edited, thanks @Erik**

Comment: First of all, it would have to be `dir(obj.__class__)`, ...but IIRC, I read somewhere that `dir` is not supposed to be used for real code and just for debugging/development, but I might be wrong.

Comment: inspect module already uses dir for introspection :S `inspect.py` lines 247 to 251

Comment: me neither, just curious after your comment :P good to know that